# Чем отличается статический метод от статистического свойства функции?

Tags: javascript

Правильно ли я понял, что единственное различие в js «статических методов и свойств» от «свойств функции», лишь в написании названии функции с большой буквы (общепринятое соглашения для того чтобы можно было отличить функцию конструктор от обычной функции).

На всякий случай напишу, что свойством функции вполне может быть другая функция.

**Пример «статического свойства».**

```
function ExampleSt(){
     //...
}
ExampleSt.pr="dp";

ExampleSt.pr; // = "dp"
```

**Пример «статического метода».**

```
function ExampleSt(){
     //...
}
ExampleSt.mt = function() { return "Статические метод" }

ExampleSt.mt(); // = "Статические метод"
```

**Пример «свойства функции» с использованием обычного свойства.**

```
function example(){
     //...
}
example.pr="dp";

example.pr; // = "dp"
```

**Пример «свойства функции» с использованием функции.**

```
function example(){
     //...
}
example.f = function() { return "Свойства функции в виде функции" }

example.f(); // = "Свойства функции в виде функции"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На самом деле в вопросе приведено два **совершенно** одинаковых примера.

И в обоих случаях устанавливаются свойства *конкретной* функции.

*Статическими* их можно назвать *только* в контексте того, что если использовать функции как конструкторы, то в создаваемых объектах это свойство будет отсутствовать, и доступ к ним будет осуществляться только по имени *класса*.

Comment: Спасибо! Я понял, что когда писал про большую/маленькую букву, не подумал, что ведь вполне возможно технически, если захотеть наделить функцию написанную с маленькой буквы возможностями конструктора, то её вполне можно использовать в качестве него и наоборот.

Напишу ответ на свой вопрос своими словами, для того чтобы убедиться, что я Вас правильно понял: **«метод функции»** будет являться **«статическим»**, только если сама функция которой он принадлежит используется в качестве конструктора, тоже правило действует и для **«статический свойства»**.

Comment: @taiiku, не совсем. **Любая** нормальная функция, может использоваться в качестве конструктора, для этого ее надо просто вызвать с ключевым словом `new`. Имя функции при этом не играет никакой роли. Таким образом, можно сказать, что функция определяет какой-то класс объектов. Для этого _класса_ любое собственное свойство функции _можно считать_ статическим.

Comment: Grundy, благодарю за уточнение, теперь точно все понятно!

Answer (score 3):

Вы, похоже, не понимаете, что такое метод, а что такое свойство. Динамическое или статическое -- это в данном контексте не важно.

По порядку на пальцах:

свойство -> это характеристика,
метод -> это действие

К примеру,

```
function Rabbit () {
    this.name = 'Кроль'; //это характеристика == свойство
    this.color = 'white'; //это тоже характеристика == тоже свойство

    //далее идет функция == действие == метод
    this.sayHello  = () => { 
         alert('Привет, я ' + this.name)
      };

    // Это тоже функция == действие == метод
    // несмотря на то, что это выполнение этого действия вернет
    // значение свойства "color"
    this.returnColorOfThisRabbit = () => {
       return this.color
    }

    // И даже это функция == действий == метод
    // хоть и её вызов вернет просто строку, 
    // которая могла бы быть просто свойством
    this.returnEasyWord = function(){
       return 'Easy'
    }

}
```

Методы объекта -- это только функции.
А все, что не является методом объекта -> это его свойство.

Теперь вернемся к статическим свойствам/методам:

```
 function Rabbit(){
    ...
 }


 Rabbit.age = 7
 // это статическое свойство
 // статическое потому что не относится к самому создаваемому объекту
 // если точнее, то это свойство функции-конструктора, но не объекта  


 Rabbit.sayYourAge = function(){
     alert(this.age);
     //В данном контексте this == Rabbit
 }
 //это статический метод
```

Comment: это все сложности терминологии. property в js может быть как значением, так и функцией - разницы нет.

Comment: Метод — это функция, ассоциированная с объектом или, проще говоря, метод — это свойство объекта, являющееся функцией. Методы определяются так же, как и обычные функции, за тем исключением, что они присваиваются свойству объекта. -> Цитата с https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: А я про методы и не говорил ничего :-) я говорил про _property_ и лучше было вставить цитату сверху: _Значением свойства **может быть функция**, которую **можно назвать** методом объекта._ А можно продолжать называть ее свойством :) И опять все уперлось в _сложность с терминологией_ :)

Comment: По такой логике, что же тогда называют методом в js?

Comment: Ты же написал определение метода :) не знаю чего ты к нему прицепился, если я про методы ничего не писал :)

Comment: А, да, ты прав.. не до конца прочитал вопрос.

Comment: уважаемый @Grundy а это стандарт Ecmascript? => написано тут this.sayHello  = () => { 
?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов, да, [стрелочные функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) появились в ES6

Comment: @Grundy благодарю :)

Comment: Благодарю, что вы заметили у меня в пример эту ошибку. Я обычно примерно такой же методики и придерживался, но для функций я почему-то решил сделать исключение, еще раз спасибо за внимательность!

Answer (score 1):

Разница в том, что «статическое свойство» - это свойство самой функции как конкретного экземпляра, а «свойство» - это свойство экземпляров возвращаемых функцией.

```js
function ExampleSt() {
  return this;
}

ExampleSt.property = "MyStaticProperty"

function Example() {
  this.property = "MyProperty"
  return this;
}

var instance = new ExampleSt();
console.log(instance.property);//undefined
console.log(ExampleSt.property); 

var instance = new Example();
console.log(instance.property);
console.log(Example.property);//undefined
```

По поводу отличия свойства от метода. В js все методы являются частными случаями свойств. Если свойство объекта возвращает функцию, то это свойство - метод.

```js
function Example() {
  this.property = "This is Property";

  this.method = function() {
    return "This is Method";
  }

  return this;
}

var example = new Example();
console.log(example.property);
console.log(example.method());
```

Comment: Последний сниппет делает не то, что Вы думаете. Без new это не работает. И свойство, и метод добавляются в глобальный объект, т.е. window

Comment: Спасибо. Не знал, что это так работает. Добавил new в примеры. Это несколько не логично по-моему.

Comment: Хотя нет, все логично. function Example() получается метод глобального объекта window.

Comment: _function Example() получается метод глобального объекта window_ - это тебе только в этом примере повезло, что ты их глобально объявляешь, если ты объявишь эту функцию **внутри** другой функции, то поведение не изменится, но доступа к функции из window уже не будет